# glShaderSource access violation when using Win32 to read files

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, file-io

So, I'm trying to setup basic OpenGL scene using only Win32 API and OpenGL, but I've big problems with loading shaders and glShaderSource function. I'm reading my file like this:

```
//HEADER

class FileReader
{
public:
    FileReader(const LPCSTR FileName);

    const void* GetFileData();

    ~FileReader();
private:

    HANDLE FileHandle;

    void* FileDataMemory;
};

//ACTUAL CODE

FileReader::FileReader(const LPCSTR FileName)
{
    FileHandle = CreateFileA(FileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (FileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("Failed to open file ");
        OutputDebugStringA(FileName);
        OutputDebugStringA(" for reading, application could not be loaded\n");
        ExitProcess(-2);
    }

    unsigned int FileSize = GetFileSize(FileHandle, 0);
    DWORD BytesRead;
    FileDataMemory = VirtualAlloc(0, FileSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    ReadFile(FileHandle, FileDataMemory, FileSize, &BytesRead, 0);
    if (BytesRead < FileSize)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("File was not read completely\n");
    }
}

const void* FileReader::GetFileData()
{
    return FileDataMemory;
}

FileReader::~FileReader()
{
    CloseHandle(FileHandle);
}
```

And I use this class to load vertex shader from disc like this:

```
    VertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(VertexShader, 1, static_cast<const GLchar* const*>(VertexShaderFile->GetFileData()), 0);
```

But my app gives me an access violation reading address 0xFFFFFFFF on line with glShaderSource. And I'm just so confused, because when I try to see this block of memory in debug mode, it looks properly and has correct data insisde it, so I just don't know what to do.

Comment: Is there are particular reason, why you want to limit yourself to the Win32 API? The only reason I can think of is if you want to avoid linking against the C and/or C++ standard library, to reduce the executable size. And that you'd usually do when creating a demo or an intro. But for those you'd normally pack all asset data into the executable itself. So I'm a bit puzzled about this. You normally don't use the Win32 API directly, unless you're into code masochism.

Comment: No, it was just for learning purposes, I decided to create a simple OpenGL app(in this case simple OBJ model viewer with texture and shading support) without any libraries(only GLEW is allowed, because without it this really becomes some kind of masochism).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shader source code string, which is read form the file is not 0 terminated.
Reserve `FileSize+1` bytes of memory and ensure that the last byte of the buffer is 0. e.g.:

```cpp
FileDataMemory = VirtualAlloc(0, FileSize+1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
ZeroMemory(FileDataMemory, FileSize+1);
ReadFile(FileHandle, FileDataMemory, FileSize, &BytesRead, 0);
```

Further, the 3rd parameter to [`glShaderSource`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glShaderSource.xhtml) is an array of strings (`const GLchar **`):

```cpp
const GLchar *source = static_cast<const GLchar*>(VertexShaderFile->GetFileData());
glShaderSource(VertexShader, 1, &source, 0);
```

What you actually do in your code is to cast `VertexShaderFile->GetFileData()`. What you would have to do ist to cast `&VertexShaderFile->GetFileData()`

---

Furthermore, I recommend to use STL to read the shader source file. e.g:

```cpp
std::ifstream sourceFile(FileName, std::fstream::in); 
std::string sourceCode = std::string( 
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Comment: @Poseydon42 I've extended the answer.